# Are video games just one big while loop?

Tags: c++

Are video games just one big ass do while loop in C++? The complex code to make a triple A video game is well, complex. But in reality when main() is called, is there just a function that runs all of the other functions in one big while loop?

I have a degree in computer science and I don't even know if that would be highly inefficient in memory. I mean wouldn't that exceed O^2 or whatever it is. Basically two nested for loops.

Maybe they use a log algorithm. I don't even know what that means. Except I guess logs, figure out the square of a number. How that helps humanity I have no idea.

But seriously, what does Triple A video game C++ code look like. Its probably really bizarre or exotic. It certainly aint anything you read or see in a training video about C++.

And why does every training material on C++ have a Employee class? WTF. Make a space ship class.

The employee is the most boring thing on the planet. A bum class would be better and more interesting.

Comment: You can check out the video game preservation Github page, https://github.com/videogamepreservation. Show how older games were made, lots of while loops. But now that asynchronous based programming has become popular other methods are being used.

Comment: @Raymond Then again, async programming necessitates an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) underneath.

Comment: If youre interested on how an AAA game code looks like, you can just read it yourself. The source code of Unreal Engine 4 is available under github.com/EpicGames.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, games typically run a [game loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure). This has nothing to do with Big O. `O(N^2)` describes an algorithm whose resource usage (usually meant as time, but sometimes memory) grows quadratically with the size of the input. A game loop does not depend on the size of any input; it is designed to run forever (or rather, till the user stops playing). However, since the game loop needs to be fast, there are constraints on things that get called from the game loop, in order for the game not to stutter; these subroutines do have inputs (e.g. sprites to render, game objects that need collisions tested...), and one would typically want to make sure these subroutines run as efficiently as possible — so Big O is applicable.